# How to replace all return type from class intypescript

Tags: typescript-generics

I want to change methods return type for implement RPC.

```js
class Original {
 hello(): number;
 world(a: number): string;
}

Class Magic<T> {
...(something I want...)
}

new Magic<Original>()
// => likely
{
 hello(): Promise<number>;
 world(a: number): Promise<string>;
}
```

How to make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slightly round about way to achieve this -

```
class Original {
    hello(): number { return 2 }
    world(a: number): string { return "str" }
}

type Magic<T> =  {
    [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends (...args:any[]) => any ? (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => Promise<ReturnType<T[K]>> : never
}

type IMagic = Magic<Original>

class OtherClass extends IMagic {
    // implement your methods here
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBOBLA5ogdmE0DeAoaB0AFgKYggD2AFAJQBc0aArgLYBGJ8O08JALk3hpoAJmgBffIQDuFeCAAmVMA2btO9aBD5I0ybrwFDoAIm3wTE3JNx8AngAcS0ALJhUwADwAVAHzQAXgI8QmgAbQBpaHRoAGsSOwoAM2hvAF06KQJvSLToEgAPPhI0BRgqADoqsHhkCDowNDswtJpA-0a7aAB+aErq2vroAAUasBZ+TggfXN82gP9h+AoWRAgSTwAlfkE0b0cNnIi0339VEgA3TmtcWwPoAEk3D0DXd0QvBBR0TF9b0EgMFgfFI8AAwuAoPkiiUyo9nh8cFloAB6FHRFgOEAkCZoPjQRKCaATEEUOGgkjWIA)